# Symfony 2 Multi tenancy architecture, data loaded form front controller/kernel based on subdomain

Tags: php, symfony, architecture, multi-tenant

Hello fellow programmers,

(a bit of background)I'm building a Symfony 2 application for university Student accommodation, when our clients from the university side register with their details a subdomain is created, students belonging to a particular university can access the online accommodation service through this subdomain, there will be several universities that will be registered and each university will have their own subdomain and separate set of related-data/student-data that cannot be accessed from other universities.

(what i have already done) i managed to create a nice login and register pages and also managed to create subdomains by editing the hosts file (*with  file_put_contents() any better way to do this using symfony?*) then i created a service that fetches the ***UniversityID*** from the parameters.yml, this way i can get university specific data since all tables have a universityID column.

should i create a script that runs before every thing is loaded that would dynamically update the ***UniversityID*** inside the parameters.yml based on the subdomain? ***what is the best practice for this***

In conclusion, what i want from the community is,

1). i'm looking to use the Front controller to load the **University Specific** data, how do i load/set dynamic data using front controller and/or Kernel

2). how to create subdomains from dynamically without being platform (OS) specific

-thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this dynamically you can base your solution on the following tutorial: http://knpuniversity.com/screencast/question-answer-day/symfony2-dynamic-subdomains .

You have a University dataset, that holds the university name and the subdomain(maybe the name slug).

Then you create a event listener that on every request will parse the URL and extract the subdomain and fetch the university with that subdomain.

If you are using DoctrineBundle, you can create a Filter to filter your results by the current university.

Comment: Thank you @joao that was a useful link, +1 for the info, and more importantly i'm looking for a solution where i can load universityID using front controller and/or Kernel, you think i could use an event listener to do this? i'm still exploring symfony, i will try the method you suggested and get back to you on this, if that front controller thingy works out for me i will gladly accept your answer.